# upgrading posgresql 9.0 to 9.4 with pg_upgrade on CentOS 6.6

Tags: postgresql, linux

I'm trying to upgrade a postgres v9.0 database to v9.4 with pg_upgrade on CentOS 6.6, but I keep hitting a wall.

I am calling pg_upgrade thru a shell script as postgres, first exporting the needed variables for PATH, PGHOST and LD_LIBRARY_PATH. So far, so good. Prior to that the services are stopped successfully (the port lock file in `/tmp` is removed, also the `.pid` file in the data folder) and the `pg_upgrade` starts doing its magic. It checks compatibility and tries to start the old database, but it keeps failing. Here are the logs:

```
su -l postgres<<-_EOF_
    export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/db/pgsql_94/bin"
    export PGHOST="localhost"
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib:/path/to/lib"
    /path/to/db/pgsql_94/bin/pg_upgrade --old-datadir=/path/to/db/pgsql_90/data --new-datadir=/path/to/db/pgsql_94/data --old-bindir=/path/to/db/pgsql_90/bin --new-bindir=/path/to/db/pgsql_94/bin -v -p 6543 -P 5432
_EOF_


Running in verbose mode
Performing Consistency Checks
-----------------------------
Checking cluster versions                                   ok
pg_control values:

First log file ID after reset:        0
First log file segment after reset:   6
pg_control version number:            903
Catalog version number:               201008051
Database system identifier:           xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Latest checkpoint's TimeLineID:       1
Latest checkpoint's NextXID:          0/1731
Latest checkpoint's NextOID:          34237
Latest checkpoint's NextMultiXactId:  1
Latest checkpoint's NextMultiOffset:  0
Latest checkpoint's oldestXID:        654
Latest checkpoint's oldestXID's DB:   1
Latest checkpoint's oldestActiveXID:  0
Maximum data alignment:               8
Database block size:                  8192
Blocks per segment of large relation: 131072
WAL block size:                       8192
Bytes per WAL segment:                16777216
Maximum length of identifiers:        64
Maximum columns in an index:          32
Maximum size of a TOAST chunk:        1996
Date/time type storage:               64-bit integers
Float4 argument passing:              by value
Float8 argument passing:              by value
Current pg_control values:

pg_control version number:            942
Catalog version number:               201409291
Database system identifier:           xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Latest checkpoint's TimeLineID:       1
Latest checkpoint's full_page_writes: on
Latest checkpoint's NextXID:          0/1810
Latest checkpoint's NextOID:          13004
Latest checkpoint's NextMultiXactId:  1
Latest checkpoint's NextMultiOffset:  0
Latest checkpoint's oldestXID:        1800
Latest checkpoint's oldestXID's DB:   1
Latest checkpoint's oldestActiveXID:  0
Latest checkpoint's oldestMultiXid:   1
Latest checkpoint's oldestMulti's DB: 1
Maximum data alignment:               8
Database block size:                  8192
Blocks per segment of large relation: 131072
WAL block size:                       8192
Bytes per WAL segment:                16777216
Maximum length of identifiers:        64
Maximum columns in an index:          32
Maximum size of a TOAST chunk:        1996
Size of a large-object chunk:         2048
Date/time type storage:               64-bit integers
Float4 argument passing:              by value
Float8 argument passing:              by value
Data page checksum version:           0


Values to be changed:

First log segment after reset:        000000010000000000000002
"/path/to/db/pgsql_90/bin/pg_ctl" -w -l "pg_upgrade_server.log" -D "/path/to/db/pgsql_90/data" -o "-p 6543 -c autovacuum=off -c autovacuum_freeze_max_age=2000000000  -c listen_addresses='' -c unix_socket_permissions=0700" start >> "pg_upgrade_server.log" 2>&1

*failure*
There were problems executing ""/path/to/db/pgsql_90/bin/pg_ctl" -w -l "pg_upgrade_server.log" -D "/upath/to/db/pgsql_90/data" -o "-p 6543 -c autovacuum=off -c autovacuum_freeze_max_age=2000000000  -c listen_addresses='' -c unix_socket_permissions=0700" start >> "pg_upgrade_server.log" 2>&1"
Consult the last few lines of "pg_upgrade_server.log" for
the probable cause of the failure.

connection to database failed: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 6543?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 6543?


could not connect to old postmaster started with the command:
"/path/to/db/pgsql_90/bin/pg_ctl" -w -l "pg_upgrade_server.log" -D "/path/to/db/pgsql_90/data" -o "-p 6543 -c autovacuum=off -c autovacuum_freeze_max_age=2000000000  -c listen_addresses='' -c unix_socket_permissions=0700" start
Failure, exiting

Failed to upgrade database to v9.4
```

The error shows `connection refused`, but I doubt that is the issue. Both `.hba` files are in `trust` auth-method.

I've been observing the socket lock files, the old dabatase cluster is instructed to start on port 6543, and while `pg_ctl` is executing, the lock file for 6543 is created, but `pg_ctl` doesn't return I guess. `pg_upgrade` calls `pg_ctl start` with the `-w` flag, meaning it waits 60 secs for the start(and I timed it, and it fails after about a minute).

The `pg_upgrade_server.log` is very sparse and that is what makes me think that the timeout is the problem.

```
command: "/path/to/db/pgsql_90/bin/pg_ctl" -w -l "pg_upgrade_server.log" -D "/path/to/db/pgsql_90/data" -o "-p 6543 -c autovacuum=off -c autovacuum_freeze_max_age=2000000000  -c listen_addresses='' -c unix_socket_permissions=0700" start >> "pg_upgrade_server.log" 2>&1
waiting for server to start...............................................................pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
```

Anyone remotely familiar with this problem, please share with me your 2 cents, it would be most appreciated.

Anyways, the question - Can I give `pg_ctl` a longer wait time when it starts the clusters via `pg_upgrade` ??? Or is that the root of my problem at all ?

The only lines not commented out of (v9.0's) `postgresql.conf` are

```
port = 5432             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 200           # (change requires restart)

shared_buffers = 240MB          # min 128kB
                    # (change requires restart)
work_mem = 4MB              # min 64kB
checkpoint_segments = 12        # in logfile segments, min 1, 16MB each
log_destination = 'stderr'      # Valid values are combinations of
logging_collector = on      # Enable capturing of stderr and csvlog
log_directory = '../../../log/db'                   # directory where log files are written,
                                                                                # can be absolute or relative to PGDATA
log_filename = 'postgresql-%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S.log'  # log file name pattern,
log_min_messages = notice       # values in order of decreasing detail:
log_min_error_statement = fatal # values in order of decreasing detail:

log_min_duration_statement = 5000   # -1 is disabled, 0 logs all statements
log_line_prefix = '%t [%p]: [%l-1] '            # special values:
statement_timeout = 10800000            # in milliseconds, 0 is disabled

datestyle = 'iso, mdy'
lc_messages = 'C'           # locale for system error message
                    # strings
lc_monetary = 'C'           # locale for monetary formatting
lc_numeric = 'C'            # locale for number formatting
lc_time = 'C'               # locale for time formatting
default_text_search_config = 'pg_catalog.english'

max_locks_per_transaction = 200     # min 10
                    # (change requires restart)
default_with_oids = on
```

Thanks,
Dragan

Comment: Could you show the non-commented lines of the old cluster's `postgresql.conf`?

Comment: added them to the post.

Comment: Also, if I run `pg_ctl` on its own, it fails after 60 sec with and empty log file...

Comment: Do you run `pg_ctl start`?

Comment: Anyway, the problem looks like `pg_upgrade` tries to connect via TCP/IP, while the cluster is configured to allow socket connections only.

Comment: I tried to run `pg_ctl` on it's own, and it failes without ANY logs...

Comment: I ran it afterwards with the `-W` flag, and tried to connect to the database (`psql`) but it cannot connect, although the `.pid` file is there, and the port lock files...

Comment: I made some progress, the problem lies in the `pg_ctl -c listen_addresses=''`. It should be `-c listen_addresses='*'`, and I uncommented it from the `postgresql.conf` ( `listen_addresses='*'` ) but pg_upgrade seems to ignore whats set up there. I tried overriding it with `pg_upgrade ... -o "-c listen_addresses='*'"` but the old setting also appears after the custom one and overrides it again... Basically, it seems like `pg_upgrade` calls `pg_ctl` with hardcoded params, because you know, fuck us right?

Comment: anyone know a workaround for this by any chance?

Comment: 2 years have passedn and same problem here. Did you found a solution or a workaround?